# A rotated line through the whole screen

Tags: html, css

I want to have a slightly rotated line separating  my site content, But when I try to rotate the `<hr>` line, it never ends properly, leaving ugly gaps.

How could I get lines that go through the whole screen?

```css
.dividingline {
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="dividingline">
  <hr style="margin-top: 50px; margin-bottom: 0px; width:200%; position:relative; left:-1200px; border-width:10px; border-style: solid; border-color: #e82010; border-radius: 24px; background-color:#e82010; height:30px">
  <hr style="margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 0px; width:200%; position:relative; left:-1200px; border-width:10px; border-style: solid; border-color: #fe5b20; border-radius: 24px; background-color:#fe5b20; height:30px">
  <hr style="margin-bottom: 50px; margin-top: 0px; width:200%; position:relative; left:-1200px; border-width:10px; border-style: solid; border-color: #f26c8f; border-radius: 24px; background-color:#f26c8f; height:30px">
</div>
```

Comment: First off, it's much easier to debug this is your styles weren't all defined inline on a single line, but in your CSS itself. Secondly, you center these lines using `width : 200%` and `left: -1200px` - which will not be responsive, you should probably use `transform: translateX(-50%)`. Your `overflow: hidden` is, however, the thing that breaks most - it will cut off the lines after rotation, which I presume is not what you want?

Comment: What does your content look like? What should it look like once this is implemented? Have you considered using a background-image ([`linear-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient)) for example, or [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)? This can be done in an almost infinite number of ways, and - depending on your use-case(s) - there may be better, potentially more responsive, ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid overflows the [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) needs to be set at the start of the line. And instead of rotating entire `<div>` rotate each line individually:

```css
.dividingline {
  margin-top: calc(tan(5deg) * 100vw);
}

.dividingline>hr {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 15px 15px;
  
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
}

.dividingline>:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #e82010;
}

.dividingline> :nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #fe5b20;
}

.dividingline> :nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #f26c8f;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation.</p>
<div class="dividingline">
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

In the output click on "Full page" and resize the browser window. The lines don't overflow out of screen or cover any text lines.

Answer (score 1):

Use `vw` units (less than 100) so that once rotated the element does not overflow and then remove the positioning.

This is now responsive and I've centered it as well.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.dividingline {
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
  overflow: hidden;
}

hr {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 98vw;
  position: relative;
  border-width: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 24px;
  height: 30px;
}

hr:nth-of-type(1) {
  border-color: #e82010;
  background-color: #e82010;
}

hr:nth-of-type(2) {
  border-color: #fe5b20;
  background-color: #fe5b20;
}

hr:nth-of-type(3) {
  border-color: #f26c8f;
  background-color: #f26c8f;
}
```

```html
<div class="dividingline">
  <hr>
  <hr>
  <hr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a slight rotation so better consider `skew`. Visually you will get the same result and you won't have any overflow issue.

```css
.dividingline {
  transform: skewY(-3deg);
  margin-block: calc(tan(3deg)*100%);
}

.dividingline hr {
  border-radius: 99px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 2px;
  border: none;
}


body {
 margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="dividingline">
  <hr style="background-color:#e82010;">
  <hr style="background-color:#fe5b20;">
  <hr style="background-color:#f26c8f;">
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```css
.dividinglineContainer {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* height: 400px; */
  min-height: 260px;
}

.dividinglineContainer::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.dividingline {
  transform: rotate(-5deg) scaleX(2);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  top: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dividinglineContainer">
  <div class="dividingline">
    <hr style="margin-top: 50px; margin-bottom: 0px; width:200%; position:relative; left:-1200px; border-width:10px; border-style: solid; border-color: #e82010; border-radius: 24px; background-color:#e82010; height:30px">
    <hr style="margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 0px; width:200%; position:relative; left:-1200px; border-width:10px; border-style: solid; border-color: #fe5b20; border-radius: 24px; background-color:#fe5b20; height:30px">
    <hr style="margin-bottom: 50px; margin-top: 0px; width:200%; position:relative; left:-1200px; border-width:10px; border-style: solid; border-color: #f26c8f; border-radius: 24px; background-color:#f26c8f; height:30px">
  </div>
</div>
```

How about this?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).